# How to delete all points/coordinates within a (parametrically defined) ellipse

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, scikit-image, ellipse

I have some data which looks like this:

[image]

I've drawn an ellipse around some of the data using `from skimage.measure import EllipseModel`
I was able to fit the ellipse by providing the package with B0_M data and the corresponding q^2 between 5200 and 5350, and then I was able to extract some parameters from the fit, to plot the ellipse myself, as follows:

```
X1Y1 = np.column_stack((X1,Y1))
ell = EllipseModel()
ell.estimate(X1Y1)
xc, yc, a, b, theta = ell.params
```

where `X1` is the full B_0 data and `X2` is the full q^2 dataset. It returned the following values for the ellipse parameters:

```
a = 0.399894
b = 37.826
xc = 5272
yc = 9.27
theta = 1.573
```

Unfortunately this fit was not perfect, so I scaled some of the parameters, or added some small numbers etc, essentially to tinker to get the fit shown in the figure. Here is how I plotted the ellipse fit:

```
xc, yc, a, b, theta = ell.params
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
dt = 0.01*theta
ell_x = xc + 2*a*np.cos(theta+dt)*np.cos(t) - 1.8*b*np.sin(theta+dt)*np.sin(t)
ell_y = yc + 0.47*a*np.sin(theta+dt)*np.cos(t) + 0.47*b*np.cos(theta+dt)*np.sin(t)+0.26
plt.scatter(X,Y, marker = '.', alpha = 0.05, color = 'navy', s =0.2)
plt.scatter(xc, yc+0.26, color='red', s=10)
plt.plot(ell_x, ell_y, color = 'red')
plt.xlim(5150,5400)
plt.ylim(7,12)
plt.xlabel('B0_M')
plt.ylabel('$q^2$')
plt.title('jpsi')
```

Now I'd like to remove all of the points, from `X1` and `Y1`, that are inside the ellipse

How can I do this? I wanted to use a simple mathematical argument like basically using the equation of an ellipse, but it is more complicated since I have it in parametric form, and its also not the most tidiest thing since I have scaled different variables by different amounts as I said before.

Is there some way to simply say, "delete points in X, Y if they are inside the ellipse with coordinates ell_x and ell_y"?

Many thanks

Comment: What are `X1` and `Y1`?

Comment: I defined it near the beginning, its basically the full experimental data (B0_M as the x-coordinates, and q^2 as the y coordinates). The purpose of this is to remove any points that lie within the ellipse, are they are physically useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the equation for an ellipse to construct a mask that isolates the points outside your model.
The trick is to transform your `X1` and `Y1` into the ellipse's coordinate system by shifting and rotating them using `xc`, `yc`, and `theta` before applying the ellipse equation.

```py
dx = X1 - xc
dy = Y1 - yc

x2 = dx * np.cos(theta) + dy * np.sin(theta)
y2 = -dx * np.sin(theta) + dy * np.cos(theta)

mask = np.square(x2 / a) + np.square(y2 / b) > 1

X1_outside = X1[mask]
Y1_outside = Y1[mask]
```

Note: I expected that [`skimage.measure.Ellipse`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#ellipsemodel) would have some method that makes this easier, but I can't find it after a quick read through the docs. If anyone knows how to do this using `Ellipse` that would be much more readable.

Comment: just a very small typo, on your second line shouldn't it be dy = Y1 - yc
? Similarly on the final line shouldn't it be Y1_outside = Y1[mask]

Also do I need to do the transformations when I have ell_x and ell_y, which are the coordinates that lie on the perimeter of the ellipse?

Comment: Just fixed the typos, sorry about that! As to your second question, I don't think those coordinates are very useful since you would have to interpolate them to find the line dividing the inside of the ellipse from the outside, and it still wouldn't be as accurate as using the equation of the ellipse directly.